# How to find files in subfolders from txt file and copy them?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, copy

I have a txt file that include **only** the names of files that are in different sub-folders, I'm trying to write a function that will find this files and copy them to specific folder.

This is an example of my dir:

```
1
├── 2
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── b.txt
│   └── c.txt
│  
└── 3
    ├── d.txt 
    └── e.txt
```

This is an example of files_name.txt file:

```
a.txt
c.txt
e.txt
```

I tried this function I found those files but I couldn't copy them.

```
xargs -d &apos;\n&apos; -a files_name.txt -I FILENAME find 1 -type f -name FILENAME -exec cp {} DESTINATION_FOLDER: \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about xargs, but the following should loop over your text file and copy the file into the destination folder one by one.

```
while read p; do
    find 1 -name "$p" -exec bash -c 'cp "$1" DESTINATION_FOLDER' _ {} \;
done < files_name.txt
```

Comment: Looks good - but is the bash subshell really necessary? wouldn't `-exec cp {} DESTINATION_FOLDER \;` or `-exec cp -t DESTINATION_FOLDER {} \;` work just as well?

Comment: Don't see why not. Guess I'm just used to using the subshell form like this... I think security problems arise when you do `-exec sh -c 'echo {}'\;`, for example, so that's something to watch for